# Googe Home Device Details - IPs

Tags: dialogflow-es

When using GH device integrated with Dialog Flow, while conversation starts from google home and back to webhook requests, can we get the the GH device details, like the speaker name, IP, WAN IP if used?

Answer (score 0):

No, the data that would identify an individual device are not provided to your Dialogflow agent.